# which SPRoleDefinition.BasePermissions responsible to mark discussion board list's items as featured. if i want to create a cusotm permission level

Tags: 2013, development, powershell, custom-permission-level

I have the following inside my sharepoint on-premises 2013 farm:-

1. Team site collection, which have the publishing featured enabled.
2. Inside the Team site collection, i added a Discussion Board list.
3. Now users with built-in Contribute permissions, can add,edit, delete discussion board items.
4. But seems they can not mark their own or other users items as featured, where this option is only available to site admins:-
   [image]

so i am planning to create a custom permission level using power-shell, which have the exact permission as the built-in Contribute, but with the ability to mark Discussion Board items as featured. so i am not sure which `SPRoleDefinition.BasePermissions` is responsible to enable marking items as featured? now i find this link which list the available permissions, but i can not find the permission to allow "Mark as featured"??
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2008/06/26/what-permissions-are-behind-the-permission-levels-roles-in-sharepoint/